# Pass Formula Field into Parameter Field

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to pass a formula field into a parameter field in crystal reports?

**Example**

*Parameter*

{?JobNumber}

- String
- Discrete and Allow multiple values

User inputs job number 33882 and there are associated jobs with this job number. (ie. 33882, 33768)

So I want to pass the associated jobs into the parameter field (as an array?). So instead of the record selection selecting the one input (masterid = {?JobNumber})(33882), the record selection selects the associated jobs (masterid = {?JobNumber})(33882, 33768).

Comment: Why aren't you using a cascading parameter?  Master job, then associated job.

Comment: you could also do this using a sub-report by taking the job id and converting it to a masterid. then passing the masterid into the sub-report.